# Event sourcing in microservices: separate event stores + system-wide event store?

Tags: architecture, microservices, event-sourcing

Say each microservice is using event sourcing which means it has it's own event store, do you typically add another "mother" event store that contains all events from all microservices as a source of truth on how each system communicated?

E.g.,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say each microservice is using event sourcing which means it has it's own event store, do you typically add another "mother" event store that contains all events from all microservices as a source of truth on how each system communicated?

No, but sort of.

Typically, separate micro-services means that any given stream has a single *logical* authority that "owns" the responsibility for maintaining the stream invariant.  Common practice (to simplify management) is to arrange your streams so that all streams owned by the same service are shared together in a single logical event store.

You can, of course, have multiple microservice sharing the same physical event store(s).

Where things get interesting: writes are targeted to a single stream, but *reads* are very often interested in events that may be written to many streams -- or more precisely to *copies* of events written to many streams.

Assuming you are comfortable with some latency, it doesn't particularly matter that the readers aren't connected to "the" authoritative copy of the stream, as long as the information that they do get is internally consistent (ie, a true snapshot of the stream at some point in the not-necessarily-immediate past).

So yes, you *could* add a mother store, decoupling most of the read traffic from the stores that are managing the writes (in much the same way that you might have RDBMS replicas supporting queries).

I wouldn't call it "typical" though - especially given that the replica (in your micro service example) is being created from multiple different stores.

Answer (score 0):

It depends why you want to cobain it. Services should be separate domain contexts so it doesn't make sense to keep them together as they don't provide additional value together. Although it is quite common to use a broker (e.g. Apache Kafka) to distribute events and allow flexible distribution to your service's event stores as well as durability and reliability.